# Writing dictionaries recursively

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON file with location data. Below is a sample from the file.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Western Cape",
    "filename": "1",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Eastern Cape",
    "filename": "2",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Northern Cape",
    "filename": "3",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Free State",
    "filename": "4",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "KwaZulu-Natal",
    "filename": "5",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "North West",
    "filename": "6",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Gauteng",
    "filename": "7",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Mpumalanga",
    "filename": "8",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Limpopo",
    "filename": "9",
    "type": "Province",
    "typeCode": 1
},
{
    "id": 199,
    "name": "City of Cape Town",
    "filename": "1.199",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 260,
    "name": "Buffalo City",
    "filename": "2.260",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 2
},
{
    "id": 299,
    "name": "Nelson Mandela Bay",
    "filename": "2.299",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 2
},
{
    "id": 499,
    "name": "Mangaung",
    "filename": "4.499",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 4
},
{
    "id": 599,
    "name": "eThekwini",
    "filename": "5.599",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 5
},
{
    "id": 797,
    "name": "Ekurhuleni",
    "filename": "7.797",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 7
},
{
    "id": 798,
    "name": "City of Johannesburg",
    "filename": "7.798",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 7
},
{
    "id": 799,
    "name": "City of Tshwane",
    "filename": "7.799",
    "type": "Metropolitan Municipality",
    "typeCode": 2,
    "parent": 7
}]
```

I am looking to achieve the following output:

```
{'Eastern Cape': {u'Buffalo City': {}, u'Nelson Mandela Bay': {}}, 'Gauteng': {u'Ekurhuleni': {}, u'City of Johannesburg': {}, u'City of Tshwane': {}}, 'North West': {}, 'Mpumalanga': {}, 'Limpopo': {}, 'Western Cape': {u'City of Cape Town': {}}, 'KwaZulu-Natal': {u'eThekwini': {}}, 'Northern Cape': {}, 'Free State': {u'Mangaung': {}}}
```

I have written the following code block to achieve it:

```
province_dict = {}
final_dict = {
    'Western Cape': {},
    'Eastern Cape': {},
    'Northern Cape': {},
    'Free State': {},
    'KwaZulu-Natal': {},
    'North West': {},
    'Gauteng': {},
    'Mpumalanga': {},
    'Limpopo': {},
}

for item in data:
    if item['type'] == 'Province':
        province_dict.update({item['id']: item['name']})

for item in data:
    if item['type'] != 'Province':
        if item['parent'] in province_dict.keys():
            final_dict[province_dict[item['parent']]].update({item['name']: {}})


print final_dict
```

However, there seems to some problems:

1. This isn't the most pythonic way to achieve this.
2. I am not limited to Province and Metro Municipality, I also have District Municipalities and so on. They are however all governed by the same rules every child has a parent id with the Province being the root.
3. I need to create a hierarchical structure as mentioned above with n number of nesting possible.

It would be helpful if someone could help me achieve this.

Comment: why recursive? you can iterate and solve this problem i think.

Comment: I think this should be posted in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Sometowngeek I would have, had this been the complete solution, since it is not I posted it here, as to show what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to create an **abstract data type** to do that efficiently. You could have the ADT class use a dictionary and you could give it another property.

This is just pseudocoding. I don't have time at the moment to create a fully functional class, but I think this would help.

```
class SomeClass:
    _parents = {}
    _children = {}

    def add_obj(self, obj):
        if obj.noParent:
            self._parents[obj.get_id] = obj

        else:
            self._children[obj.get_id] = obj

    def to_string(self, id):
        for v1 in (self._parents if id is None else self._parents.get(id)):
            if v1.get_id in self._parents.keys():
                print(self.to_string(v1.get_id()))
            for v2 in self._children.get(id):
                print(v2.stuff)
```

If you are still struggling, when I have time either later today or tomorrow, I'll come back to this answer and see if I can make it functional.